# Clear left второго уровня сбрасывает float left первого уровня

Tags: float, html, вёрстка, css

Доброго дня, уважаемое сообщество.
Вопрос для тех кто верстает и знаком с использованием float и резиновых div.

Предположим простую верстку:

```
<div class="left-side"></div>

<div class="right-side">
  <div class="sub-float"></div>
  <div style="clear:left;"></div>

  <div class="broken-div"></div> <!-- there is a bug -->
</div>

<style>

  .left-side {
    float:left;
    width:200px;
  }
  .right-side {
    margin-left:200px;
  }
  .sub-float {
    float:left;
  }

</style>
```

После отработки clear, отчистится обтекание left-side( не смотря на то что он на уровень выше )
  И broken-div будет показан ниже left-side и весь остальной контент страницы тоже ( При том что он находится на уровень ниже в рамках соседнего div )

Это все происходит потому что у right-side нет float:left и он является резиновым блоком на всю ширину.
Да, именно из за этого я не могу **построить список из float второго уровня внутри резинового блока**

И что тогда делать, написать для right-side float:left и width и отказаться от резиновости макета только потому что внутри такого блока я не могу использовать float:left для построение внутренних элементов ?

Comment: Надо выстроить блоки в ряд? Для такого создан display: inline-block

Comment: Да, я уже так и сделал, думаю эту ситуацию с float не разрешить..

Answer (score 2):

Ответ это overflow:hidden, с его помощью можно не использовать clear, или использовать редко.

Все вот здесь:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540485/how-to-make-an-inline-block-element-fill-the-remainder-of-the-line